# is it possible to add a string template to views in a .net mvc project?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, stringtemplate

I have a newbie question,, how do i add a string template to the views folder in a .net mvc project?

I have added a reference to `StringTemplate.dll` and `antlr.runtime.dll?` but seems that is not enough.

i.e. when i right-click on views and choose `Add >> New Item` i can't find a file with .st extension in the list that i get...
how do i achieve that?

Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, by choosing Add >> New Item then writing filename.st in the Name field, i haven't found another way to do that yet, but it would be great to have a stringtemplate document type.